# Copy/Paste Named Ranges within Workbook

Tags: excel, copy-paste, named-ranges

This might be a duplicate post, so please let me know if so; a cursory search didn't seem to indicate so.

How do I duplicate ranges in the "Name Manager" dialog box? I'm creating some dynamic scatter plots and want to save some time manually inputting every name and OFFSET(). The only parameters to be changed are "Name" and "Refers To", i.e. this is all within one workbook.

The latter simply needs new column references, i.e. =OFFSET(ABS!$A$3,0,0,COUNTA(ABS!$A:$A),1) would become =OFFSET(ABS!$D$3,0,0,COUNTA(ABS!$D:$D),1) etc.; no material changes to the formulae.

The best I've done so far is clicking and dragging to highlight the bit in "Refers to", then clicking "New" and pasting the formula, then making the changes. There has to be a quicker way...

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the Name Manager dialog pictured in your question:

A. Select the name whose range you want to copy

B. Click edit

C. Tab down to the "Refers To" text box. The entire definition should be selected

D. Copy (CTRL-C)

E. Cancel

Now you're back in the Name Manager

A. Click New...

B. Type the new name of a range

C. Tab down to the "Refers To" text box.

D. Paste (CTRL-V)

E. VERY IMPORTANT: Push the F2 key to switch to edit mode

F. Edit to suit

G. Optional: Set Scope, add comment

H. Click OK